# Cmd line CSV merge error

Tags: excel, csv, command-line, merge

I merged many CSV files from the command line. However, when opening the resulting file in Excel, the first row of each CSV is appended to the last row of the previous CSV. I have tried other means of merging but the same thing occurs.

For example: 
From the command line I run:

```
copy *.csv all.csv
```

Row 56 of CSV #1 is a,b,c

Row 1 of CSV #2 is 1,2,3

Merged CSV would be a,b,c1,2,3

Anyone have a clue as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Next script shows some merging (in fact, appending) scenarios:

- *simple COPY*: approves described line concatenation if very last line in a file lacks standard line ending i.e. <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>;
- *loop COPY*: fixes above issue but could add some empty lines to the output file;
- *loop TYPE*: same as *loop COPY*;
- *loop ECHO*: probably the best solution allows to handle e.g. CSV headers properly (if present);
- append <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> in advance before simple COPY: same as *loop COPY* but is very simple and could be written as a oneliner

  - `del all.csv&(for %G in ( *.csv ) do @>>"%~G" echo()&copy *.csv all.csv /B`

Please note that `copy *.csv all.csv` without the ending `/B` switch could put <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> character to the `all.csv` end.

**Script**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

    REM change the current directory to a test folder 
pushd d:\bat\files\folder

    REM create sample input files (optional) 
call :createSampleInputFiles

echo(
echo --- simple COPY:
2>NUL del all.csv
>NUL copy *.csv all.csv /B
    REM (debugging, optional) show output file
findstr "^" all.csv

echo(
echo --- loop COPY:
2>NUL del all.csv
    REM create empty output file: necessary
>NUL copy NUL all.csv
for %%G in (*.csv) do (
  if NOT "%%~G"=="all.csv" (
    >NUL copy all.csv + %%G all.csv /B
        REM add an empty line unconditionally
    >>all.csv echo(
  )
)
findstr "^" all.csv

echo(
echo --- loop TYPE: same as --- loop COPY
2>NUL del all.csv
    REM create empty output file: possible but not necessary
rem >NUL copy NUL all.csv
for %%G in (*.csv) do (
  if NOT "%%~G"=="all.csv" (
    >>all.csv type %%G
        REM add an empty line unconditionally
    >>all.csv echo(
  )
)
rem findstr "^" all.csv

echo(
echo --- loop ECHO:
2>NUL del all.csv
>all.csv (
  for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b *.csv') do (
    if NOT "%%~G"=="all.csv" (
      for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%g in ( "%%~G" ) do (
            REM ToDo: (optional) if not 1st file then skip copying CSV header  
        echo(%%g
      )
    )
  )
)
findstr "^" all.csv

    REM for completeness - add <CR><LF> in advance, then simple COPY:
echo(
echo --- add ^<CR^>^<LF^> before simple COPY: same as --- loop COPY 
2>NUL del all.csv
for %%G in ( *.csv ) do >>"%%~G" echo(
>NUL copy *.csv all.csv /B
rem findstr "^" all.csv

    REM change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by PUSHD
popd

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:createSampleInputFiles
      REM create sample input files 
  2>NUL del *.csv
  for %%g in ( x y z ) do (
    >i%%g.csv (
          REM write CSV header (optional)
      rem echo(Ca,Cb,Cc
      for %%G in ( 1 2 ) do (
        echo(a%%g%%G,b%%g%%G,c%%g%%G
      )
      if "%%g"=="x" (
            REM last line with trailing <CR><LF>
        echo(a%%gL,b%%gL,c%%gL
      ) else (
            REM last line without trailing <CR><LF>
        <NUL set /P "=a%%gL,b%%gL,c%%gL"
      )
    )
  )
      REM show sample input files
  rem type *.csv
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> D:\bat\SO\40682173.bat

--- simple COPY:
ax1,bx1,cx1
ax2,bx2,cx2
axL,bxL,cxL
ay1,by1,cy1
ay2,by2,cy2
ayL,byL,cyLaz1,bz1,cz1
az2,bz2,cz2
azL,bzL,czL
--- loop COPY:
ax1,bx1,cx1
ax2,bx2,cx2
axL,bxL,cxL

ay1,by1,cy1
ay2,by2,cy2
ayL,byL,cyL
az1,bz1,cz1
az2,bz2,cz2
azL,bzL,czL

--- loop TYPE: same as --- loop COPY

--- loop ECHO:
ax1,bx1,cx1
ax2,bx2,cx2
axL,bxL,cxL
ay1,by1,cy1
ay2,by2,cy2
ayL,byL,cyL
az1,bz1,cz1
az2,bz2,cz2
azL,bzL,czL

--- add <CR><LF> before simple COPY: same as --- loop COPY

d:\bat>
```